# If I turn off swap using swapoff -a and use RandomAccessFile to write some data will it every flush to disk?

Tags: java, linux

If I turn off swap using `swapoff -a` and use RandomAccessFile to write some data will it every flush to disk? Assume I am not calling `RandomAccessFile.getFD().sync()`

Comment: Yes. `RandomAccessFile` has nothing to do with system swap. Disk buffers are also unrelated to swap.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Thanks for that. But then what does swapoff mean then? I thought swapoff means virtual memory paging is completely off. And if I understand correcttly, RandomAccessFile will leave it to OS to do the flushing of the mmapped pages and if so shouldn't swapoff effect the RandomAccessFile behavior?

Comment: @user1870400 "virtual memory paging" is used when you use more memory than you have RAM. It has nothing to do with file access.

Comment: @user1870400 Doesn't look like RandomAccessFile is based on mmap. It just calls write on the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn got it but Imagine I do `RandomAccessFile.getChannel().map.put(bytes)`

Comment: @user1870400 You are mistaken about what "swap" and "virtual memory paging" is. The comment was not just to inform you of that, but is phrased as a question because I am truly interested in knowing why/how you came to the belief that "swap" had anything to do with file access. I really want to know, that's why I **asked**!

Comment: @user1870400 If you wanted us to imagine that you're using `getChannel()`, you should have said so in the question. If that is your real question, I *suggest* you edit the question text and clarify it.

Comment: I *recommend* you read [Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager - Chapter 11: Swap Management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, `RandomAccessFile` does not do any buffering, so calls to `RandomAccessFile` go straight to the OS `write` call.

If you call `getChannel` and then call `FileChannel.map`, presumably the runtime will use `mmap` to map the file. In that case, the question becomes, when do writes to a `mmap` buffer get flushed to disk? Obviously it would be insane for the OS to flush every single byte written to the buffer. The answer is that the OS will periodically flush changes to disk, or you can call `msync` or (from Java) `MappedByteBuffer.force`.

`swapoff -a` does not affect any of this behavior. In the case of `RandomAccessFile`, the runtime calls `write`, which has nothing to do with memory or swap space. In the case of `mmap`, the buffer visible to the program is backed not by swap space but by the file.

Answer (score 1):

`swapoff` is about memory-to-disk swapping. Let's say you have 4GB of RAM, and you start an app that takes 3GB. Then you launch another app that also needs 3GB. The system now has to choose; either it can just refuse to do it and show an error dialog. Or, it takes some of the memory of the first app (at least 2GB worth of it), write it out to a file (or in linux' case, a dedicated partition), and then use that memory for the new app. Then, if you switch apps back to the original, it'd have to write a bunch of the second app's memory to disk and reload back into memory from disk the first app.

That's swap. In ye olden times when RAM was grievously expensive, swap was *CRUCIAL* for the success of multitasking OSes. These days where most modern machines sell with 4 to 32 GB of RAM in standard kit, far less so, and many systems (notably including iphones and android) forego it entirely.

THAT is what `swapoff` is about. It has nothing whatsoever to do with mmapping files.

If you want to test flushing, there's a fairly simple trick: write 1 byte at a time, explicitly calling flush in between, and time doing that 5000 times or so. Then do it again this time without the explicit flush. If it takes about as long, flushing is implicitly happening. To confirm that it'd be faster, load up a 5000-sized byte array and write that (so, 1 write call to write 5000 bytes, instead of 5000 write calls to write 1 byte), see if THAT is faster. It should be.

You can read the API docs of the various methods as to whether they make any guarantees.

If they don't, then that means you don't know: On one system it may flush, and then on another it may not. If you write your code such that your code fails (doesn't work at all, or is teeth-grindingly inefficient and slow) if it's not like the system you tested it on, that's on you.